# Tumblr Custom URL Not Working

Tags: url, tumblr

I have bought a domain that I want to use as a unique Tumblr website but I can't get the url to pick up on Tumblr settings.

The domain is a .com registered with 123-reg. I've set the CNAME to the correct tumblr url and also set the A record too. When I visit the url I get the Tumblr error page so I know that the domain is pointing, however when I go to settings in Tumblr and "Test" the url it says that it's not pointing and I can't save it. What could be the problem?

Comment: How can you set both a CNAME and an A record at the same time?  Are you talking about different subdomains?

Comment: Did you enter your domain name into tumblr's system and test it with the following instructions? http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

Comment: I've set the A record back so just using CName now. I've just done exactly the same thing with a .co.uk url of mine and that's working fine

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't completed the "Post-login steps" from http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

> 1. Click Settings (the gear icon) at the top of your Dashboard.
> 2. Click the blog you’d like to update on the right side of the page.
> 3. Click the pencil to the right of the ﻿username﻿ section and enable "Use a custom domain."
> 4. Enter your domain (e.g. mywebsite.com) or subdomain (e.g. blog.mywebsite.com).
> 5. Click “Test your domain.”
> 6. Correct problems if the test finds any, and click “Test your domain” until the test is successful.
> 7. Hit “Save.”

Until you complete these steps, the Tumblr server won't know which tumblr account with which to associate this domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently, and it usually takes some time for the A record to update before tumblr's test button will recognize that it is set up.